# Stored Procedure to return different data based on ID

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been using this method if I need to do different actions in a stored procedure that isn't update insert or delete. Mostly if I have to do a select to show different information depending on the person role. I was told this is very bad practice and bad performance but I don't see how can I do this without having to write a stored procedure for each command and that looks even worse because I have so many commands. My question is, is there a better way to do this type of thing in SQL Server?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spRequisicao
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spRequisicao
    -- hRequisicao
    @Action NVARCHAR(20),
    @MotivoCriacao NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @IdCodeRequest INT = NULL,
    @Projecto NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Desenho NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Indice NVARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @CadenciaMensal INT = NULL,
    @NumCOMDEV NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @RefCliente NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @RefInterna NVARCHAR(7) = NULL,
    @QTDLancamentoFormas INT = NULL,
    @CapacidadeReal NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Peso FLOAT = NULL,
    @IdCaixa INT = NULL,
    @IdComp INT = NULL,
    @IdMetProd INT = NULL,
    @IdColaborador INT = NULL,
    @IdStatus INT = NULL,
    @IdInfoLogistica bit = NULL,

    -- hDataLog
    @IdData INT = NULL,
    @DataAbertura DATETIME = NULL,
    @DataAlteracao DATETIME = NULL,
    @IdReq INT = NULL,

    -- hCaixa
    @TipoCaixa NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @QTDPecasCaixa INT = NULL,
    @UnidadeProducao NVARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @CelulaProducao NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,    
    @NumKanbansProducao INT = NULL, 

    -- hMetodologiaProducao
    @TipoMetodologia NCHAR(3) = NULL,
    @QTDMetProd INT = NULL,

    -- hComponentes
    @QTDComp INT = NULL,
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @Action = 'SELECTALL'
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            hr.IdColaborador, hr.MotivoCriacao, hr.IdReq, 
            Nome, hcb.Email, hr.RefInterna, hi.Descricao AS InfoLog, 
            hs.Descricao AS STATUS, hd.DataAbertura AS DataCriacao 
        FROM 
            hRequisicao AS hr   
        JOIN 
            hColaborador AS hcb ON hcb.IdColaborador = hr.IdColaborador
        JOIN 
            hStatus AS hs ON hs.IdStatus = hr.IdStatus
        JOIN 
            hInfoLogistica hi ON hi.IdInfoLogistica = hr.IdInfoLogistica                
        JOIN 
            hDataLog hd ON hd.IdReq = hr.IdReq
        WHERE 
            hr.IdStatus != 6
    END

    IF @Action = 'SELECTALL_USERID'
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            hr.IdColaborador, hr.IdReq, Nome, hcb.Email, hr.RefInterna, 
            hs.Descricao AS STATUS, hl.DataAbertura AS DataCriacao, hi.Descricao AS InfoLog  
        FROM 
            hRequisicao AS hr   
        JOIN 
            hColaborador AS hcb ON hcb.IdColaborador = hr.IdColaborador
        JOIN 
            hStatus AS hs ON hs.IdStatus = hr.IdStatus      
        JOIN 
            hDataLog AS hl ON hl.IdReq = hr.IdReq
        JOIN 
            hInfoLogistica AS hi ON hi.IdInfoLogistica = hr.IdInfoLogistica
        WHERE
            hr.IdColaborador = @IdColaborador AND hr.IdStatus != 6
    END 

    IF @Action = 'SELECT'
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            IdReq, hr.MotivoCriacao, hr.IdCodeRequest, hr.IdColaborador, 
            Nome, hcb.Email, Projecto, Desenho, Indice, CadenciaMensal, 
            NumCOMDEV, RefCliente, RefInterna, QTDLancamentoFormas, 
            CapacidadeReal, Peso, TipoCaixa, QTDPecasCaixa, UnidadeProducao, 
            CelulaProducao, NumKanbansProducao, QTDComp, 
            TipoMetodologia, QTDMetProd, hi.Descricao AS InfoLog 
        FROM 
            hRequisicao AS hr
        JOIN 
            hCodeRequest AS hcr ON hr.IdCodeRequest = hcr.IdCodeRequest
        JOIN 
            hCaixa AS hc ON  hr.IdCaixa = hc.IdCaixa
        JOIN 
            hComponentes AS hcp ON hr.IdComp = hcp.IdComp
        JOIN 
            hMetodologiaProducao AS hmp ON hr.IdMetProd = hmp.IdMetProd
        JOIN 
            hColaborador AS hcb ON hcb.IdColaborador = hr.IdColaborador
        JOIN 
            hInfoLogistica AS hi ON hi.IdInfoLogistica = hr.IdInfoLogistica
        WHERE
            IdReq = @IdReq
    END 

    IF @Action = 'CHECKREQ'
    BEGIN
        SELECT IdReq, IdStatus 
        FROM hRequisicao
        WHERE IdColaborador = @IdColaborador AND IdStatus = 6
    END

    IF @Action = 'CHECKSTATUS'
    BEGIN
        SELECT Descricao 
        FROM hStatus hs
        JOIN hRequisicao hr ON hr.IdStatus = hs.IdStatus
        WHERE IdReq = @IdReq
    END
END
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with having a stored procedure per command - not saying its better though.

Comment: so I should just do spSelectAllData, spSelectIDData, as an example? It would be bothersome to look for a sp in a long list of files

Comment: How often does this run?  How performant does it need to be?

Comment: It will run as often as each user with different role needs to check table with data related to each role, so it's quite often

Comment: Maybe... but is there actually a problem to solve here? Just because someone tells you its not the best way to do it doesn't mean its a problem. Unless there is actually an issue my motto is "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Comment: it can cause you parameter sniffing issues. Also makes it unnecessarily complicated to unit test with tSqlt for example

Comment: If there is a better way to do this i would rather do that if it's better. I presume a stored procedure reads from beginning to end so it must slow performance

Comment: Its only ever going to run a single query, the possible downsides are as Martin says above. But again they are only downsides if its causing a problem.

Comment: If two blocks of code are similar, like SELECTALL and SELECTALL_USERID, you can combine them (and put them into their own SP) with a WHERE clause like `WHERE ( @IdColaborador IS NULL OR @IdColaborador = hr.IdColaborador) AND hr.IdStatus != 6` (that is, @IdColaborador = NULL returns all rows).  Once you do this combination, it is perhaps a bit easier to break this into one stored procedure per command, each SP can then take the user making the request into account in its own way, if necessary.  Code at a higher level should decide which SP to call, that kind of thing should not be done in SQL.

Comment: This is a "kitchen sink" proc. The performance issue has nothing to do with reading from beginning to end. It is to do with parameter sniffing. Generally speaking it's a much better idea to have a whole set of different procs rather than one "kitchen sink" proc. This proc also appears to return different columns depending on parameters which can also cause issues and bugs if it isn't handled properly. Your proc is not doing anything that couldn't be done in the application, probably with less code.

Comment: What is the point of having all these optional arguments if you never use them? As far as I can see you are currently only using `@Action` and `@IdReq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been taught to understand that any arrangement (collection, selection, positioning etc.) of data is inherently information independent of the thing behing arranged.

The relevance of the above is that the columns and relationships represented by your various queries presumably critical to the understanding your database/application.

This means that you should be commenting and documenting them appropriately and likely separately as well.

I generally prefer to design databases (as best as I can) in a way that minimizes the amount of description necessary for future developers etc.

To do so I find that creating views based on queries such as those used in your example, naming them appropriately as well as naming the resulting columns and columns appropriate for where criteria appropriately very intuitive and easy to maintain.

In terms of performance I can't confidently advise or inform either way although I assume that it will be more influenced by the database design than sproc VS view.

**conclusion: there is no 'better' way to accomplish this task independent of the broader contextual design strategy and requirements**

Comment: Yes I thought views would be a good usage in this situation but i never implemented one and my experience with them is 0